# SOAP API issue with TrueShip

Tags: shipping, soap, soap-api-v2, ce-1.6.1.0

Our vendor is using TrueShip's ReadyShipper software to ship orders from our 1.6.1 Magento store(s). I'm not a Magento dev, but I'm not completely lost in all of this. I've also contacted support for assistance and they've been less than helpful. I've been troubleshooting an error ReadyShipper is throwing when we try to import orders:

> Magento orders download error Procedure 'salesOrderShipmentList' not
>   present

Their last advice to me was "This indicates that Magento is not setup to generate the salesOrderShipmentList through the API.".

The v1 XML does not list the referenced procedure, `salesOrderShipmentList`, but v2 XML does. Unfortunately, their software accepts the v1 soap address `http://magentohostname/index.php/api/soap/index/`, but *not* the v2_soap address `http://magentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/`.

I've enabled wsdl in Magento sys config. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error above happens when `/api/soap/` URL is used.

Please use `http://magentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap` V2 SOAP URL which is supported with the latest version of ReadyShipper 7 / Pro.

After that you'll get another error:

> Magento orders download error Procedure 'login' not present

Now the problem is with Magento when it works in `WS-I Compliance` mode it will generate error above with ReadyShipper.

**Solution**

Disable `WS-I Compliance` mode in System > Config > Magento Core API > General Settings.

If it doesn't work yet, please also disable `Enable WSDL Caching`.